# Xtext - how to extend XtextDocument class

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I need to extend XtextDocument class so i can add some properties to my dsl document.
how can it be done? 
I tried to add bind to Ui Module but there is no bind for XtextDocument.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a new binding to the ui module. All methods that follow the convention

```
public Class<? extends ${TypeToBind}> bind${SomeName}() {
  return ${MySpecialType}.class
}
```

will be invoked reflectively when the injector is created. Therefore, a binding

```
public Class<? extends XtextDocument> bindXtextDocument() {
  return MyDocument.class;
}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: That what i did, and for some reason it didn't work and now it works after i change the new class such that the constructor is being injected. thank you :)